# jQuery Highlight Nav Item on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass, nav

I'm new to HTML/CSS/JS and I'm doing some testing and fiddling around with stuff and decided to highlight a nav element when on that page. I decided to use jQuery for this because from what I read it was the easiest solution. It's worked great so far, but my issue is that it doesn't highlight the main "chat" page on load because  it's just the url, without the /index.html. I'd appreciate any help on how to get it to add the active class to the index.html element on load.

HTML:

```
 <aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.html">Chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="/friends.html">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="/settings.html">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.href; 
    $('aside nav ul li a').each(function() {
    if (this.href === path) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

SCSS:

```
  .active {
        border-right: 10px solid $accent-two;                                 
  }
```

Comment: Can you not simply remove index.html from the a tag as it will resolve to the correct address anyway?

Comment: Well, if you're on another page wouldn't it not be able to bring you back if it doesn't have a specified URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your pathname includes the entire URL, so it will never match with href in your a tag. You need to get just the page name.
Next, you should check for the href attribute of the a tag and not the href itself.
The example below uses a dummy link to aid as a demo. I had to add in the href in JS because of the snippet.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var page = path.split("/").pop();
  // 
  // The line below is for demo on stackoverflow purposes
  $("#forDemoOnStackPurpose").attr("href", page);
  //
  $('aside nav ul li a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") === page) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border-right: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="forDemoOnStackPurpose" href="">This test page</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="friends.html">Friends</a></li>
      <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example of how i will dot it. Note that i had to simulate location change with some code, but every time you run the example, it will highlight a different anchor tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Simulate change on "windows.location.href"
    //===========================================================

    var paths = ["/index.html","/friends.html","/settings.html"];
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0;
    console.log("Random idx = " + idx);

    //===========================================================

    var path = paths[idx];
    //var path = window.location.href;

    $("a").removeClass('active');
    $("a[href='" + path + "']").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    border-right: 10px solid blue;                                 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="/friends.html">Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="/settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
```